# Reuse autofac's find ctor logic

Tags: autofac

Autofac finds "best" ctor when registering a component like this

```
builder.RegisterType<MyType>()...;
or
builder.RegisterType(typeof(MyType))...;
```

I'm looking for a way to reuse Autofac's reflection code to find ctor parameters. Is this logic available in some public API?

**The reason I want above...**

I have some components with unknown types at compile time (=dynamic proxies). Currently I register them like this

```
builder.Register(c =>
{
  var dep1 = c.Resolve<IFoo>();
  var dep2 = c.Resolve<IBar>();
  var dep3 = c.Resolve<IFooBar>();
  return someProxyFactory.CreateProxyFrom<MyType>(dep1, dep2, dep3);
}...;
```

--- **Edit** ---

The same question is valid if no proxy is involved but when RegisterType cannot be used. Eg...

```
builder.Register(c =>
{
  [...]
  if(something)
   return new SomeType(dep1, dep2, dep3);
  else
   return new SomeOtherType(dep1, dep4, dep2, dep5);
}
```

Here I also would like to reuse Autofac's "find ctor logic" if possible.

--- **End edit** ---

It works fine but, if possible, I would like to use autofac's logic to find the ctor dependencies for me. I want to write something like

```
builder.Register(c =>
{
  object[] ctorDependencies = letAutofacDoTheSimilarWorkAsInRegisterType(typeof(MyType));
  return someProxyFactory.Create<MyType>(ctorDependencies);
}
```

Is this possible or do I have to write my own logic for this? Or is some completely different approach available for this scenario?

Comment: Why do those types have multiple public constructors anyway? This means that there is ambiguity between choosing them and this can be considered a design smell when doing dependency injection. Make sure every component has just a single public constructor and the problem disappears.

Comment: Why do think they have multiple public ctors? They havent. I was just looking for a way to let autofac find dependencies also when instanciated type is unknown at compile time.

Comment: my apologies,  I misread your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the answer you're after I guess, but could you use [the existing DynamicProxy2](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DynamicProxy2)? This enables you to attach interceptors to registered interfaces, much like what you are doing with your proxy factory.

**Update:** you could possibly use the `IConstructorFinder` and `IConstructorSelector` interfaces in the Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection namespace, implemented by the `PublicConstructorFinder` and `MostParametersConstructorSelector` respectively.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case no. The proxies are created by another lib.

Comment: I see. And this lib, can you not provide it with a pre-built instance instead of it requiring to do the instantiation? ...and, are you able to tell us what the lib is?

Comment: It's an internal lib here at office developed by another apartment.
But I kind of regret I mentioned "proxy" at all in the question... The same "problem" occurs if registering any component coming from some kind of factory.
It works fine as it is today, I just think it would be nicer to reuse Autofac's internal logic for finding ctor dependencies - I just kind find the API for it.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've already tried these (used from IRegistrationBuilder.ActivatorData.ConstructorSelector), but not really understood have they are supposed to be used.